# Only File is uploading to database, all other fields are NULL

Tags: javascript, mysql, file, jsp, upload

So as the title says, I'm inserting information in mysql database but only the file that I'm uploading is inserted into database. Everything else is NULL. I suspect it has something to do with the creation of temporary directory on the server to save the file but then again I can't find the solution.

**Here is the table I'm inserting into**

```
CREATE TABLE DOC(IDD INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, DOCN VARCHAR(50), AUTHOR VARCHAR(50), CAT VARCHAR(50),CONTENT MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL, CRITN INT DEFAULT 0,  PRIMARY KEY(IDD));
```

**Here is the html form I'm fiiling**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadfile.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="return verify()">      
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<span style="color:black">Τίτλος</span> <input type="text" name="title"><p></p>
<span style="color:black">Συγγραφέας</span> <input type="text" name="author"><p></p>
<span style="color:black">Κατηγορία</span> <input type="text" name="cat"><p></p>
   <td>   
      Επιλέξτε το άρθρο που θέλετε.      
   </td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>
      <input type="file" name="filename" id="filename"accept="application/pdf"/>                                                            
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**And here's the code for the jsp**

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%@page import="conPackage.MyConnection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Enumeration"%>
<%@page import="com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Properties.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.security.MessageDigest;"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%


   String rtempfile = File.createTempFile("temp","1").getParent(); 

MultipartRequest multi = new MultipartRequest(request,rtempfile, 15*1024*1024);

Enumeration files = multi.getFileNames();

String docn =request.getParameter("title");

String author = request.getParameter("author");

String cat= request.getParameter("cat");



String st="insert into doc(docn, author, cat, content) values (?,?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement psmt=MyConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(st);


String name="";
String fileExtesion="";
File ff =null;
FileInputStream fin =null;


while (files.hasMoreElements())
{
   name=(String)files.nextElement();                                        
   ff = multi.getFile(name);
   fileExtesion = ff.getName().substring(ff.getName().lastIndexOf("."));

   // check user has select the correct file or not
   boolean fileAllowed = fileExtesion.equalsIgnoreCase(".pdf");

   if((ff!=null)&&fileAllowed)
   {

     try
     {
       fin=new FileInputStream(ff);
       psmt.setString(1, docn);
       psmt.setString(2, author);
       psmt.setString(3, cat);
       psmt.setBinaryStream(4,(InputStream)fin, (int)(ff.length()));

       boolean sss = psmt.execute();

       out.print("uploaded successfully..");
       out.print("<br/> Go to <a href='downloadfile.jsp'>Download</a> page");
     }

     catch(Exception e)
     {
       out.print("Failed due to " + e);
     }

     finally
     {


           fin.close();
           ff.delete();
     }
   }
   else
   {
         out.print("Please select the correct file...");
   }// end of if and else
}// end of while

MyConnection.CloseConnection();     // close the connection
%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure, do you getting any values in these lines of code `String docn =request.getParameter("title");`. Also post your verify function too.

Comment: Go through the following [link](http://www.codejava.net/coding/upload-files-to-database-servlet-jsp-mysql) for some idea.

Comment: No I just saw I'm not getting any values. It just writes null. And if I place the `request.getParameter("title");` before `String rtempfile = File.createTempFile("temp","1").getParent();` I get 

java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending.

Comment: verify function is a script in first html
`<script>
            function verify()
            {
                if(document.getElementById('filename').value=="")
                {
                    alert('Please select the file');
                    return false;                
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        </script>`

Answer (score 0):

When using enctype `multipart/form-data` you have to use `request.getPart` for the regular parameters too, as `request.getParameter` always returns `null` with `multipart/form-data`.  The other option for processing file uploads is the Apache Commons File Upload library, but in that case as well, you have to get the regular parameters wit the same method as you get the file.

Comment: again with the getPart before the `String rtempfile = File.createTempFile("temp","1").getParent();` I get get java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending and if I place the code aftewards I get exception for null parameters.

Comment: @AlexisStratakis, I'd suggest just using Apache Commons File Upload. It works on older servers too, and its straightforward.